# Game Maker Studio 2, Shaders not working as intended in webbrowsers on mac

Tags: opengl-es2, game-maker, macos

The shader output of my html5 game in Game Maker Studio 2 looks wrong on  webbrowsers on MacOS. Sometimes the shaders lack completely and at other times the shader colors look completely different. How can I make the shaders work like they are intended to for safari webbrowsers?

See images below:

Mac webbrowser lacking shaders on squares
[image]

Other browsers not lacking shaders on squares
[image: not lacking shaders]

Mac webbrowser  different color hexagon
[image: safari different colours]

Other browsers intended colors
[image: normal colours]